# Image Height Not Displaying Right in HTML Email

Tags: html, css, html-email

The images in HTML mail top menu are not displaying right in the iPhone mail app. More specifically, the heights in some of them. Please take a look at this screenshot:

[image]

```
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                                                    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0;">
                                                                        <img src="https://images.cordial.com/91/46x68/email-menu-2020-02-04_01.jpg" alt="New!" border="0" width="46" style="display: block; max-height: 68px; max-width: 46px; width: 100%;">
                                                                    </p>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                                                    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0;">
                                                                        <img src="https://images.cordial.com/91/88x68/email-menu-2020-02-04_02.jpg" alt="Leotards" border="0" width="88" style="display: block; max-height: 68px; max-width: 88px; width: 100%;">
                                                                    </p>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                                                    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0;">
                                                                        <img src="https://images.cordial.com/91/147x68/email-menu-2020-02-04_03.jpg" alt="Design Your Own" border="0" width="147" style="display: block; max-height: 68px; max-width: 147px; width: 100%;">
                                                                    </p>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                                                    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0;">
                                                                        <img src="https://images.cordial.com/91/64x68/email-menu-2020-02-04_04.jpg" alt="Shoes" border="0" width="64" style="display: block; max-height: 68px; max-width: 64px; width: 100%;">
                                                                    </p>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                                                    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0;">
                                                                        <img src="https://images.cordial.com/91/93x68/email-menu-2020-02-04_05.jpg" alt="Costumes" border="0" width="93" style="display: block; max-height: 68px; max-width: 93px; width: 100%;">
                                                                    </p>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                                                    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0;">
                                                                        <img src="https://images.cordial.com/91/52x68/email-menu-2020-02-04_06.jpg" alt="Sale" border="0" width="52" style="display: block; max-height: 68px; max-width: 52px; width: 100%;">
                                                                    </p>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td align="left" valign="top" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                                                                    <p style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 0;">
                                                                        <img src="https://images.cordial.com/91/160x68/email-menu-2020-02-04_07.jpg" alt="Teacher Wholesale" border="0" width="160" style="display: block; max-height: 68px; max-width: 160px; width: 100%;">
                                                                    </p>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
```

CSS:

```
        table[id="backgroundTable"] { padding: 0 !important; }
        img {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
        }
        td {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

The last three images in the menu, Costumes, Sale, and Teacher Wholesale, are all different heights. This only happens on the iPhone mail app. I tested on Android Gmail, desktop, Outlook, etc., and this doesn't happen. Please help.

Comment: Do you have any other CSS in the document?

Comment: Yes, updated my question with the relevant CSS.

Comment: That's a weird one. Have you tried setting the `height` attribute on the images too?

Comment: Sean, your suggestion worked bro! It turned out that by removing the width: 100% !important; in the CSS fixed the issue. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good idea to set the `height` attribute of `<img>` elements in emails. As you mentioned in your comment, it's also necessary to remove the `width: 100% !important;` declaration from the CSS. That was likely causing the images to scale up as the table cells expanded to fill the available space.

Comment: That was it! Thanks bro. =)

Comment: @GTSJoe, if this is part of a template, you can try giving the `td's` a width in percentage so its scales with the screen. If an image with is set to 100%, the height will be proportionate **if** the `td's` resize properly. Maybe something to check out in future.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding a **min-height** property to your img tags in your css.

Such as:

```
img {
   min-height: 3em;
}
```

Comment: Why 3em specifically?

Comment: It's just a placeholder. You can put any value in there such as 100px, 1rem, 1em etc...